# How to fill an array from maple code

Tags: list-manipulation, maple

I have simple Maple code which fills 2d array with coefficients which i want to use in Mathematica for my custom functions:

```
f := array(-100..100,-100..100):
for n from - 100 by 1 to 100 do
for j from - 100 by 1 to 100 do
f[n,j] := 0:
end do:
end do:
f[0,-1] := 1;
f[1,-2] := 1;
for n from     1 by 1 to  99 do
for j from - 100 by 1 to  99 do
f[n + 1,j] := - f[n - 1,j] + (2*n + 1)*f[n,j + 1]:
end do:
end do: 
for n from     0 by - 1 to - 99 do
for j from - 100 by   1 to   99 do
f[n - 1,j] := - f[n + 1,j] + (2*n + 1)*f[n,j + 1]:
end do:
end do:
```

Is it possible to mechanically convert this to Wolfram language? Its even not allowed to create `Array[f, {-100, 100}, {-100, 100}]` because it contains negative numbers.

Answer (score 5):

```
f := array(-100..100,-100..100):
for n from - 100 by 1 to 100 do
for j from - 100 by 1 to 100 do
f[n,j] := 0:
end do:
end do:
```

can be converted to

```
n = 100;
f = ConstantArray[0, {2 n + 1, 2 n + 1}];
```

The rest can be translated to the following `Do`-loops.

```
o = n + 1;
f[[o, o - 1]] = 1;
f[[o + 1, o - 2]] = 1;
Do[
  f[[i + 1, j]] = -f[[i - 1, j]] + (2 i + 1) f[[i, j + 1]],
  {i, o + 1, o + (n - 1)},
  {j, o - n, o + (n - 1)}
  ];
Do[
  f[[i - 1, j]] = -f[[i + 1, j]] + (2 i + 1) f[[i, j + 1]],
  {i, o, o - (n - 1), -1},
  {j, o - n, o + (n - 1)}
  ];
```

But I give no guarantee for correctness. It is not the most efficient or most Mathematica-like way of doing it, but it should get you started.

Comment: @satoru Was this helpful or not? Some feedback of any kind would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The following is an incomplete imitation for the `array` function of *maple*:

```
Clear[array, eval, print]
array /: (symbol_ = array[index__]) := 
  eval@symbol ^= Array[symbol, 1 - Subtract @@@ {index}, {index}];
print = eval;
```

I've only mimic the behavior related to index, `eval`, `print`. Let's test it with examples in [its document](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=array(deprecated)):

```
v = array[{1, 4}];
Do[v[i] = i^2, {i, 4}]    
v[2]
(* 4 *)
v[0]
(* v[0] *)
eval@v
(* {1, 4, 9, 16} *)

A = array[{1, 2}, {1, 2}];
A[1, 2] = x;
print@A // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Similar enough, I think. With this `array` at hand, your code can be translated to:

```
f = array[{-100, 100}, {-100, 100}];
Do[
 f[n, j] = 0,
 {n, -100, 100}, {j, -100, 100}]
f[0, -1] = 1;
f[1, -2] = 1;
Do[
 f[n + 1, j] = -f[n - 1, j] + (2 n + 1) f[n, j + 1],
 {n, 1, 99}, {j, -100, 99}]
Do[
 f[n - 1, j] = -f[n + 1, j] + (2 n + 1) f[n, j + 1],
 {n, 0, -99, -1}, {j, -100, 99}]
```

Notice it's important to use `=` instead of `:=`.

Finally, a casual test:

```
f[-100, -99]
(*
-3349903854308016956990560304891976966494718286268537053448836660676342843505978149957098\
44989101930873893181794380748417680500201772219929015360140799620182827564370450377464294\
43359375
*)
```

[image]

OK, the conversion seems to succeed.

Answer (score 3):

Or could use `Association`

```
n = 100;
rr = Flatten[Outer[List, Range[-n, n], Range[-n, n]], 1];

ff = Association[Thread[rr -> 0]];
ff[{0, -1}] = 1;
ff[{1, -2}] = 1;
Do[ff[{i + 1, j}] = -ff[{i - 1, j}] + (2*i + 1)*ff[{i, j + 1}]
 , {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, -n, n - 1}]
Do[ff[{i - 1, j}] = -ff[{i + 1, j}] + (2*i + 1)*ff[{i, j + 1}]
 , {i, 0, -n + 1, -1}, {j, -n, n - 1}]
```

This uses 7-8 times as much memory as the method indicated by @HenrikSchumacher. The key advantage, if you will, is that you can use negative numbers in the keys.